# Automatic Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I'm a newbie in qooxdoo and I'm trying to create an automatic progress bar to use in a "Search" function.

It's seems to stop before the "setTimeout" function so it doesn't change its value

The code I'm using (popup is popup with a VBox layout):

```
var bar=new hello.automaticProgressBar();
bar.delayedLoop();
popup.add(bar);
```

My automaticProgressBar.js:

```
qx.Class.define("hello.automaticProgressBar",
{
  extend : qx.ui.indicator.ProgressBar,

    construct : function()
    {
      this.base(arguments); 
        //var i = 1;

    },
members:{
    i:1,
    delayedLoop : function()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {  
            this.setValue(10*this.i);
            this.i++;                  
            if (this.i < 11)
            {
                alert(this.i);
                this.delayedLoop();         
        }                      
    }, 300)
    }
}
});
```

Any guess?

Comment: Do you have any exception or error message?
I guess the barra.delayedLoop(); is just a type in here, right? It should be bar.delayedLoop();

Comment: Yes, you're right. I translate it from Spanish to be more clear but I forgot that one. It's bar.delayedLoop();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the context of the function argument for `setTimeout` to the current instance:

```
setTimeout(function () {  
  this.setValue(10*this.i);
  this.i++;                  
  if (this.i < 11) {
    alert(this.i);
    this.delayedLoop();         
  }                      
}.bind(this), 300);
```

Comment: +1 although I think one should poke him to using qooxdoo classes ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think the main culprit is the `setTimeout` built-in which loses the connection to the local `this`. I replaced it with `qx.event.Timer.once` and it works like a charm. See the code in this [Playground sample](http://preview.tinyurl.com/p74ldnj). Press the "Log" button of the Playground to see the log messages.